# Match ":)" smiley followed by word boundary

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match smileys followed by a word boundary `\b`.

Let's say I wanna match `:p` and `:)` followed by `\b`.

`/(:p)\b/` is working fine but why is `/(:\))\b/` behaving the opposite?

Comment: You need to understand what is exactly a word boundary. It's a limit between a character from the `\w` character class and a character from `\W` or the limit of the string (begining or end)

Comment: `p` is a word, `)` isn't.

Comment: Do you want to match `:))` or `:)%` or stuff like that too?

Comment: Could you let us know what the language is, BTW?

Comment: Javascript, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) here as `)` is a non-word character.

> Simply put: `\b` allows you to perform a **whole words only** search using
>   a regular expression in the form of `\bword\b`. A **word character** is a
>   character that can be used to form words. All characters that are not
>   *word characters* are **non-word characters**.

Use `(:\))` to match `:)` and capture it in the first capturing group.

Use `/(:\))(?![a-z0-9_])/i` in order to avoid matching any `:)`s with letters after the smiley. It is an equivalent of `(:\))\B`.

> `\B` is the negated version of `\b`. `\B` matches at every position where `\b`
>   does not. Effectively, `\B` matches at any position between two word
>   characters as well as at any position between two non-word characters.

See [demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/iB2aM1/1) and [demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/iB2aM1/2).

Comment: `/(:\))/` is matching ":)p" but I dont want that. So how should I do ?

Comment: Then, use `/(:\))(?![a-z])/i` in order to avoid matching any `:)`s with letters after it.

Comment: Actually `/(:\))\B/` is working the way I want, how do you explain that ?

Comment: `\B` - assert position where `\b` doesn't match

Comment: It is true, because `\B` matches a non-word boundary.

Comment: but it will fail if you dont want to match strings like `:),` or `:);`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Is "an equivalent of `/[a-z0-9_]/i`" better?

Comment: A little, but keep in mind that in a unicode context `\w` is equivalent to `[\p{L}\p{N}_]` and that `\w` may be different when a regex engine is compiled with different locales. So `:\)(?!\w)` <=> `:\)\B` is more waterproof. *(when lookaheads are available)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: JavaScript regex does not support Unicode classes like `\p{L}`, so in this context, I think it is equivalent.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to stribizhev's answer.. you can use `(:\))\B`

Examples for when to use what:

`\b` : string = `That man is batman.` regex = `\bman\b` matches only `man` and not the `man in batman` because position between `tm` is not a word boundary (it is a word).

`\B` : string = `I am bat-man and he is super - man.` regex = `\B-\B` matches `-` in `super - man` whereas `\b-\b` matches `-` in `bat-man` since position between `t-` and `-m` are word boundaries.. and `(space) -`, `- (space)` is not.

**Note:** It is easy to understand if you consider `\b` or `\B` as a position between two characters and if the transition from character to character is `word to word` or `word to non word`